# Rails Multiple Params Named the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working with a web service that will route a user back to my site and may append parameters about the user (I know this is poor form, but they send multiple parameters back that are the same parameter with different data). Say they collected information about what kinds of pets the user has. They'd send it back in the format of:

`&STANDARD_PETS=1&STANDARD_PETS=3&STANDARD_PETS=4&STANDARD_PETS=8`

In Rails, we seem to only grab the final parameter. So I see `parameters: {"STANDARD_PETS"=>"8"}`

Is there any way in rails to also get the other 3 `STANDARD_PETS` parameters that are passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To supplement @MilesStanfield's answer

You can use `request.original_url` to get access to the full url (including parameters)

```
require 'uri'
good_params = CGI.parse(URI.parse(request.original_url).query)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'uri'

url = 'http://www.foo.com?&STANDARD_PETS=1&STANDARD_PETS=3&STANDARD_PETS=4&STANDARD_PETS=8'
CGI.parse(URI.parse(url).query)
#=> {"STANDARD_PETS"=>["1", "3", "4", "8"]}
```